# Django app works on localhost but not Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

Right now I have a very basic app then simply displays some text. This works on both localhost and heroku. The problem is with the admin page. I am able to sign in to the admin page on localhost, but if I try to sign in on heroku, I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...
```

The *only* difference between the script running on localhost and on heroku is that the one running on heroku uses `django-heroku`. I can't find any solution anywhere to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/issues/179

Comment: @xszym I just tried it, but the same problem occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following code

> `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Thanks, I just now figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

This error
`ProgrammingError at /admin/login/ relation "auth_user" does not exist LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...` is caused due to problems in connectivity to Database or Migration error. Did you Migrate/Connect to the database properly ?

Comment: I'm not sure, because I am new to django. I will say however that it all works perfectly fine on my computer, and only causes problems when run with `django_heroku` on heroku

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what connecting *correctly* looks like?

Comment: Install  Postgresql in heroku and use dj-database-url a library which allows you to connect to a Database ,configure it to use your database url
then migrate

maybe this Link can help you out  [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what I had to do. I ran the migration commands on my computer and incorrectly assumed that I wouldn't have to run them on Heroku as well. If anyone else has this problem, here's what you have to do:

1. Go to https://heroku.com
2. Select your website
3. Near the top right corner, there will be a button labeled "more". Click that.
4. Select "run console"
5. Type `python migrate.py migrate`
6. Type `python migrate.py createsuperuser`